# MySQL backup full instance

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL after using Postgres for long time, I wonder if there's an equivalent way to backup the data like pg_basebackup in MySQL or the only option is dump?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent backup tool for MySQL is [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup).

This does not do a dump like mysqldump, it makes a physical copy of the tablespace files without blocking clients using the database. The [documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/index.html) is pretty good quality.